# Changing Drawer left and right button image dynamically?

Tags: react-native, drawer, react-native-router-flux

react-native-router-flux v3.37.0
react-native v0.42.0

[image]

I'm trying to update drawer navigation bar right image dynamically where I have used leftButtonImage, rightButtonImage, where once user read all the notification I want to change the button image.

I could not manage to re-render or update this button image, Is this feature not supported or is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: If props or state changes for the component, it should update. You should place snippets of relevant code so we could see if there are any problems.

Comment: @Gayan did you find any solutions ? please help

Answer (score 1):

You can call `Actions.refresh` when you need to refresh the view, example:

```
Actions.refresh({key: 'profileView', renderRightButton: this.renderRightButton });
```

and also define renderRightButton:

```
renderRightButton() {
    return (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={ console.log(this) } >
             <Text>Logout</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )
}
```

and lastly don't forget to import Actions from react-native-router-flux

```
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
```

Comment: this will not work where, it will override the actions and thing go wired with action missing

Comment: Share the problem in detail please.

Comment: but this will refresh the whole view ... I think this is not the good thing .. all my images are refresh .. mean all view gets reloads... 
If only this would refresh that button only......

:( :(

Answer (score 0):

You can re-render using `props` or `states` naturally.

Check the states you want, and apply image resource following the states.(or props)

```
let NotiImage = {
    normal: require('../assets/image/notinormal.png');
    new: require('../assets/image/new.png');
}

render() {
    ...

    <Image source={ this.state.newNoti ? NotiImage.new : NotiImage.normal } />

    ...
}
```